# Bootstrap 3 collapsed menu not working on mobile screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've seen this topic,
[Bootstrap 3 collapsed menu not working on mobile screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858301/bootstrap-3-collapsed-menu-not-working-on-mobile-screens)
but still couldnt resolve, i get the button, but it doesn't work

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>GREENLUX</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="http://greenlux.pt/apresentacao/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<nav>
  <div class="container"> 
    
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <!--  -->
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
      <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://greenlux.pt"><img src="http://greenlux.pt/logo_gl.png" width="125" height="21" alt=""/></a> 
      </div>
      
      
    
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="http://greenlux.pt/apresentacao/">Início <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
        </ul>
        
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-sm">
        <li><a href="#">GU10</a> </li>
        
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">E27 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Par30</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Par38</a> </li>
                      </ul>
        </li>
      
      
      <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">R7S <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li>&emsp;360º</li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">78mm</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">118mm</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">138mm</a> </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li>&emsp;180º</li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">118mm </a> </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        
        <li><a href="#">G24</a> </li>
        
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">2G11 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">10W</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">32W</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">SPOT <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Redondo</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Quadrado</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">DOWNLIGHTS <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">15W</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">30W</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        
        <li class="dropdown"> 
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">PLAFON 
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Redondo</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Oval</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        
        <!--
        
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a> </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a> </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        
        -->
        
      </ul>
      
      <!--
      
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-sm">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a> </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a> </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      -->
      
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse --> 
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid --> 
</nav>


<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
<script src="http://greenlux.pt/apresentacao/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> 
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
<script src="http://greenlux.pt/apresentacao/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and btw, how can i put the menus open by mouse hover?
i've tried already and couldn't do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put at least a class of `navbar` on your nav tag. But apperently there was something else wrong so here is a working example of the default navbar. From there you can change the CSS to your liking. I also added one change to make the dropdowns appear on hover.

https://jsfiddle.net/gno4zcrr/1/

```css
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://greenlux.pt">
        <img src="http://greenlux.pt/logo_gl.png" width="125" height="21" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li><a href="#">GU10</a> </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">E27 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Par30</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Par38</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </li>


        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">R7S <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li>&emsp;360º</li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">78mm</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">118mm</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">138mm</a> </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li>&emsp;180º</li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">118mm </a> </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">G24</a> </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">2G11 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">10W</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">32W</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">SPOT <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Redondo</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Quadrado</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">DOWNLIGHTS <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">15W</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">30W</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">PLAFON 
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Redondo</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Oval</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```